# Cannot start MYSQL Database - No error messages

Tags: mysql, startup

I am trying to start up the database using :

> service mysqld start

and all I am receiving in return is:

> MySQL Daemon failed to start.
>   Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]

I have no error messages in the log files, neither error logs nor mysqld.log

Does anyone have any idea please?

Comment: Do you need to run with sudo?

Comment: @zero298 Please refrain from trying to solve every problem with sudo!

Comment: @fancyPants I understand that, but I’m pretty sure MySQL installs as a root service on most distributions by default. With that consideration, and lacking log files, we can at least assess if this is a permissions issue or something else.

Answer (score 2):

check your err file if not viewing any logs or error problem can be .ini/.cnf file save your .ini/.cnf file encoding it should be ANSI.

`my.ini -> edit notepad++ -> encoding -> ANSI -> save`

Answer (score 0):

MySQL probably can't or doesn't know where to write the error log.

Check that every directory and file you specified in your my.cnf exists and is writable and owned by the mysql user.

With files I mean for example

```
basedir    =  /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir     =  /var/lib/mysql/tmp
```

With files I especially mean

```
log-error  =  /var/log/mysql/mysqld-error.log
```

Then you should see something in your error log, if there still is a problem.